# How is battery percentage calculated in Debian with i3?

Tags: bash, debian, i3, battery

I have written a bash script to alert me whenever the battery percentage gets lower than some predefined threshold. However I've realized than the battery percentage that I compute is different (~6% higher) than the one that is displayed in the status bar of i3 (I am on Debian). Here is how I calculate the battery percentage:

```
ENERGY_MAX=$(cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_full | bc)
ENERGY_NOW=$(cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_now | bc)
ENERGY_NOW_PRCT=$(echo "($ENERGY_NOW*100/$ENERGY_MAX)" | bc)
```

What is the formula used by Debian/i3 to calculate the battery percentage?

Which one of the two is the more representative of my real battery level?

Answer (score 0):

You may need it:

````
cd /proc/acpi/battery/BAT0;
max=$(grep 'design capacity:' info|awk '{print $3}')
current=$(grep 'remaining capacity:' state|awk '{print $3}')
percent=$(expr $current"00" / $max )
echo -e "Current capacity: \t$current"
echo -e "Max capacity:  \t$max"
echo -e "Percent: \t\t$percent"```
````